# Learning linux development

Tags: kernel, development

I am interested into learning development of Debian. I learnt and I am actually learning advanced abstract mathematics, so I will propably not have problems with understanding, but actually I do not have almost no knowledge of computers and similar things. Is there anyone who could recommend me some book or other source of complete tutorial for basics of development of linux based operating systems? It should be rather "harder", because then it is going to be shorter and it will propably has more informations inside. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian is an *aggregator* - it collects and packages code from thousands of upstream developers. Debian Developers generally tweak upstream code (that they did not create) in order to fix bugs and eliminate conflicts with other software. Those upstreams do most of the actual code-writing. Most Debian volunteers test and package that code.

- If you want to *write* code (programs), participate in an upstream that you find interesting.
- If you want to *package* code into deb packages, pick code (or an existing package) that you find interesting and join http://mentors.debian.net

There is no single book or tutorial -- the subject is much too broad. Find an element or activity that interests you, and look for a primer on that specific topic.

Comment: But where should I start? Is there some start point, where I can get wider view of what would be interresting for me and then how to start with that thing? Thank you very much.

Comment: No volunteer has found it worthwhile and fulfilling to create such a start point for folks who have have "*almost no knowledge of computers*." If you think (today) that you want to develop, then start learning a programming language. Python3 is a good choice. There are lots of good choices. If you decide (tomorrow) that you don't want to *develop* after all, but want to do something else, your experience today will help fill in the roles and vocabulary that you need to express it.

Comment: Ok. I have one final question. Where could I learn, how the whole system work? Does exist some scheme on document, that says, what happens and why it happens and so? It should not be too exact, it should be somethink to just understand how the whole system should work. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's essentially the same question: A single document, written for a beginner, that explains *everything*. There isn't one; that's whole bookshelves and years of learning. It's like asking how the ocean works -- there are too many possible answers; the question is currently too vague to be usefully answerable. If you refine your question to include the kinds of topics that you think might interest you, we can offer some suggestions. The way most folks get involved is by helping to Triage bugs ...but that requires some understanding of code and process.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Best regards.